# What is the type of '()->{}' in Java 8?

Tags: java, types, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

In Java8, what is the type of the following lambda ???

```
() -> {}
```

That is a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing.

Stated differently:

```
public class A {
  static void a(){}
  static void main(String[] args) {
    ???? a = A::a
  }
}
```

What should I replace the question marks with?

In Scala, this would be a `Function0[Unit]` I think, but I don't find anything alike in Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike Scala, lambdas in Java don't have a fixed type. Rather they take the type of whichever interface you declare the variable as, as long as that interface defines exactly one abstract method and that method has the same signature as the lambda.

So in your case, you want an interface that defines a void method that takes no parameters. `Runnable` would be one example of that.

Comment: …as long as that interface defines exactly one **abstract** method…

Comment: @Holger Right, interfaces can contain non-abstract methods now. I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: And to be clear, `interface Foo { void m(); }` is also a perfectly valid target for this lambda. Java lambdas do not have a type per se, rather they have a compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Stuart for the answer:

```
java.lang.Runnable a = () -> {};
```

Now that you stated it, it seems perfectly obvious...

Comment: It's easy to miss, because it's not in `java.util.function` like most of the rest of the functional interfaces.